# Not displaying Woocommerce product page in lightbox

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic, jquery, lightbox

I have installed a plugin named "WP Post Popup" . It is easy to use and allows any link to show in a lightbox.  I have entered the below code

```
$wproduct = get_post( $wproduct_id  );  
$wslug = $wproduct->post_name; 
$product_pop = '<a class="modal-link" href="/product/' . $wslug . '"/>View</a>';
echo $product_pop;
```

It is rendering the Lightbox. But the lightbox is not displaying its content correctly. Like this 
[image: The texts that are showing is the product description]

Comment: How is it displaying it? How bad is it? Can you show us?

Comment: It is just displaying the product description only

Answer (score 0):

you are adding the name of product in a's tag of href

```
<a class="modal-link" href="/product/' . $wslug . '"/>View</a>
```

you need to add products html link in this like below

```
<a class="modal-link" href="example.html"/>View</a>
```

i hope it work.

lightbox link ex:

```
<a href="http://www.yoursite.com/yourpage.htm" class="html5lightbox" data-width="960" data-height="600">Link to Page</a>
```

Comment: Buddy, I don't want to display the Product image in lightbox. I want to load the complete product page in the lightbox!

Comment: okay sorry about it. now first print the $wslug and see the full url